# Suppose $U \sim Unif(0,1)$ and $Z \sim Unif(U,3+U)$. How can I find the pdf for $U + Z$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

Suppose $U \sim Unif(0,1)$ and $Z\mid U \sim Unif(U,3+U)$. I would like to find the pdf for $U + Z$, which in my process on $Z$ is a continuation of $U$. Is there a straightforward way to derive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like we have another uniform random variate, call it $V$ such that:

$$V \sim \text{Unif}(0,3)$$ and  $$Z \sim U \star V \quad \text{(convolution)}$$ so that $$Z= U+V.$$

So now, $$U+Z = 2U + Z.$$

Let $$W=2U$$ so $$W \sim \text{Unif}(0,2).$$

$$U+Z = W+V \sim \text{Unif}(0,2) \star \text{Unif}(0,3).$$

The distribution will be a trapezoid:

$$ \left\{  \begin{array}{ll} 
\frac{y}{6}, & 0 < y \le 2 \\
\frac{1}{3}, & 2<y\le 3 \\ 
\frac{5-y}{6}, & 3<y<5 
\end{array} \right.$$

[image]

Comment: could you tell me how you decided to define $V \sim Unif(0,3)$? thanks!

Comment: Looking at your definition of $Z$, we see that $Z$ is the sum of $U$ and another uniform variate.  First pick $U$, then add $V \sim \text{Unif}(0,3).$

Comment: I don't know if this comment really explains it.  Let me ask you, "if you were writing code (or otherwise generating random numbers), how would you produce a realization of $Z$?"

Comment: Hi, I think I may have generated confusion with my notation. I meant to have: suppose $X$ follows a Uniform(0,1) variate. Then suppose that $W$ given $X$ follows a Uniform(X, 3+X) distribution. So $W$ is conditionally uniform based on the generated $X$, and not another random uniform

Comment: Assuming that you mean $U$ and $Z$, the two formulations are equivalent.  You can generate $U$ uniformly, then define $Z$ to be uniform with endpoints $(U,U+3)$ or you can generate $U\sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$ and $V\sim \text{Unif}(0,3)$ and let $Z=U+V$.

Comment: This is not a proof, but could give us intuition.  Just a suggestion:  Please code it up both ways.  Generate $100,000$ or so random numbers from the distribution of $Z$, expressed one way and the other way, and plot histograms for both sets of random points.